# component props destructuring error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the flowing code in my component, I keep getting the error:

Unexpected token (9:8), which if the return statement.

Can anyone help?

```
export class Flexible extends React.Component {

  const { style, children, ...rest } = this.props;
  return <View {...rest} style={styles.flexible}>{children}</View>;
}
```

Comment: You seem to miss the render function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a class, which only accepts properties and functions.

It looks like you are trying to create the `render` method - let's do that then:

```
export class Flexible extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { style, children, ...rest } = this.props;
    return <View {...rest} style={styles.flexible}>{children}</View>;
  }
}
```

If you don't need state or any of the life cycle functions (`componentWillMount` etc), you can get away with just creating a functional component:

```
export const Flexible = (props) => {
  const { style, children, ...rest } = props;
  return <View {...rest} style={styles.flexible}>{children}</View>;
};
```

It's understandable to get the two mixed up - they do look kind of similar to the untrained eye :)

Hope this fixed your issue!